# sum of squares matrices

Tags: c++

I want to do a function that given 2 matrix returns the sum of both.I think the problem is in how I initialize the Matrix 't'.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
typedef vector< vector<int> > Matrix;
    Matrix sum(const Matrix&a,const Matrix&b){
           Matrix t;
           for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++)
               for(int j=0;j<a.size();j++)
                   t[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];


           return t;
    }
```

Comment: what's this matrix class? What constructors does it have (you have to set its size...)?

Comment: Matrix is declrades as a matrix: typedef vector< vector<int> > Matrix;
Then I want a function that returns the sum of 2 matrix given,my problem is that this code doesn't works,probably because I have to initialize the  variable t?

Comment: well, how did you create a & b? :)

Comment: Sorry,is not a class,is a function and 'Matrix' is defined with typedef.

Comment: "I think the problem is in..." <-- you've never told us what you're trying to do, what your input is and how the result does not match your expectations. In this case we can guess, but it would  normally be nice to add this to your question.

Comment: I didn't create,that's the problem,how I initialize Matrix?In java i know but in c++ nope...

Comment: @user1198085: just a sidenote: vector is a templated class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to initialize the rows and columns of `t` with something like:

```
Matrix t = vector< vector<int> >(row_count, vector<int>(col_count, 0));
```

That will make a `row_count` by `col_count` matrix filled with zeroes.

---

On a side note about performance: comparing to `.size()` in a for loop means that before each iteration, `.size()` has to be calculated again.  You can save a bit of processing (which adds up for massive data sets) by pre-calculating it like so:

```
for (int row = 0, row_ct = mat.size(); row < row_ct; ++row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a rectangular data set in general: each `a[i]` is a vector of a possibly different length. Supposing you do in fact take care to have a rectangular grid, your for loop is still off; it should be like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
{
    assert(a.size() <= b.size() && a.size() <= t.size());

    for (int j = 0; j < a[i].size(); j++)  // !!
    {
        assert(a[i].size() <= b[i].size() && a[i].size() <= t[i].size());
        t[i][j] = a[i][j] + b[i][j];
    }
}
```

I added some assertions to indicate which preconditions you have to satisfy.

To initialize a rectangular array, you can do something like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> v(n_rows, std::vector<int>(n_cols, 0));
```

Comment: In this case, the vectors in the data set are guaranteed to be the same size, mainly because if they weren't, it wouldn't be a matrix.

Comment: @GigaWatt: Your data *type* doesn't enforce this structure, though. You are describing a lucky runtime coincidence, rather than taking advantage of a strongly-typed, compiled language.

Comment: In fact,yes they are squares,otherwise I would have done what you had saied.

Comment: @user1198085: This sort of nested dynamic allocation is *very* expensive. Why not have a single flattened vector of size `M * N` that you access in strides, like `i + N * j`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean,a single vector? I want a matrix.

Comment: @user1198085: yes yes, I'm just talking about how to *store* the matrix. You flatten it out into one single sequence of numbers, that's far more efficient.